# TypeScript shared projects

Tags: typescript, reference, project, shared

In short, I understand that using *references* in tsconfig, I should be able to set things up so that I can have a monorepo with a shared project, with client and server projects that can access stuff in the shared project.

I have found several github repos that have this type of thing set up already, but have yet to find any good documentation/tutorials/etc on how to set this up from scratch, or more importantly, how to refactor an existing project, breaking shared logic into a separate, referenced project.

I am relatively new to the js/ts world, but I'm surprised to find that something like this isn't simpler/better documented.

Comment: Do you plan to use any frameworks? I can recommend https://nx.dev/

Comment: While I'm not adamantly opposed to using a framework/library, I would prefer to not introduce more dependencies for what appears to be supported in typescript natively.

Comment: I have never done it myself but I can point you to this article that is about multiple tsconfigs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html also you can look up what angular does as it will create multiple tsconfigs and they have it working right...

Comment: @LeedanJohnson have you found a proper solution meanwhile?

Comment: In short, no. I tried everything I could find/think of for several hours, and finally ended up adopting a terrible solution of just copy/pasting the shared folder around  between projects as I make changes. It won't be sustainable, but I can't afford to sink more time in trying to set it up right now.